# Gradle: Can I place one root project within another?

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, git-submodules

**Question:** Can I do the following or will this lead to problems?

```
MyAndroidGradleProject
|-- settings.gradle
|-- build.gradle
|-- app
|   +-- build.gradle
+-- SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject
    |-- settings.gradle // root project within root project!
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- app
    |   +-- build.gradle
    +-- library
        +-- build.gradle
```

Where `MyAndroidGradleProject/settings.gradle` looks like this:

```
include ':app'
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File('./SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject/library')
```

As far as I can tell, everything seems fine, but I don't want to run into problems later on... **Can someone confirm that this fits with Gradle's design?**

**Why would you even do that?**

The reason for my directory structure is that I want have `SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject` as a git submodule within the git repository of `MyAndroidGradleProject`. I currently have both projects sitting side by side in the same parent directory like this

```
AndroidStudioProjects
|-- MyAndroidGradleProject
+-- SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject
```

But that way of course I cannot have one as the submodule of the other. I could of course have a third git repository in a common parent folder that has both other repositories as submodules but that seems both overly complicated and semantically wrong.

Comment: Yes you can do it, also if the best option in this case could be to have a maven dependencies instead of a git submodule.

Comment: Thank for your reply! Yes, I know... And we keep promising ourselves that _soon_ the library will be stable enough to publish it to a private Maven repository and import it via Gradle. But for now, we'd have to deploy new versions every few days and update the version used... On the other hand, git submodules have their own overhead... But at least we now know what the options are. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Based on your structure, I removed the *second* `settings.gradle`:**

```
MyAndroidGradleProject
|-- settings.gradle
|-- build.gradle
|-- app
|   +-- build.gradle
+-- SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject
    |-- app
    |   +-- build.gradle
    +-- library
        +-- build.gradle
```

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = "MyAndroidGradleProject"

include ":app"
include ":SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject"
include ":SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject:app"
include ":SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject:library"
```

`build.gradle`

// apply common plugins here

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
```

**SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject**

A `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` are not needed here

**SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

dependencies {
   compile project(":SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject:library")
}
```

**SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
```

This setup will allow you to have and compile two different apps in the same git repo. Ideally when compiling, you want to only compile 1 at a time, so make sure to select the tasks accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from SO for a while. I should have mentioned in my question that I can't really change the content of `SomeLibraryAndroidGradleProject`. Suppose it's some library from Github that for some reason I need to use in source form. These are usually packaged as a Gradle project with two modules, one for the actual library and one for a small example app. But thank you very much for your detailed reply!